# Columns misaligned in attempt to delimit tabular data in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

Here is what my tabular data file looks like

```
            P(days)         growth
  0       0.67150E+01    -0.11654E-02
  1       0.47166E+01    -0.15529E-02
  2       0.35861E+01    -0.12327E+00
  3       0.28754E+01    -0.30987E+00
  4       0.23721E+01    -0.48377E+00
  5       0.20062E+01    -0.63666E+00
  6       0.17097E+01    -0.17122E+01
  7       0.16867E+01    -0.86038E+00
  8       0.14523E+01    -0.55203E+00
  9       0.12864E+01    -0.37704E+00
```

I am attempting to read this into a data frame. I tried this:

```
LINAData = DataFrame(CSV.File(LINAFile, skipto = 2, header = 1, delim=' ', ignorerepeated=true))
```

But as you can see:

```
│ Row │ P(days) │ growth  │
│     │ Int64?  │ Float64 │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 0       │ 6.715   │
│ 2   │ missing │ 1.0     │
│ 3   │ missing │ 2.0     │
│ 4   │ missing │ 3.0     │
│ 5   │ missing │ 4.0     │
│ 6   │ missing │ 5.0     │
│ 7   │ missing │ 6.0     │
│ 8   │ missing │ 7.0     │
│ 9   │ missing │ 8.0     │
│ 10  │ missing │ 9.0     │
```

Is there an issue with how I am delimiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header is missing column name for the first column, so you have to supply it manually:

```
julia> LINAData = CSV.read(LINAFile, DataFrame, skipto = 2, header = ["","P(days)", "growth"], delim=' ', ignorerepeated=true)
10×3 DataFrame
│ Row │       │ P(days) │ growth     │
│     │ Int64 │ Float64 │ Float64    │
├─────┼───────┼─────────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 0     │ 6.715   │ -0.0011654 │
│ 2   │ 1     │ 4.7166  │ -0.0015529 │
│ 3   │ 2     │ 3.5861  │ -0.12327   │
│ 4   │ 3     │ 2.8754  │ -0.30987   │
│ 5   │ 4     │ 2.3721  │ -0.48377   │
│ 6   │ 5     │ 2.0062  │ -0.63666   │
│ 7   │ 6     │ 1.7097  │ -1.7122    │
│ 8   │ 7     │ 1.6867  │ -0.86038   │
│ 9   │ 8     │ 1.4523  │ -0.55203   │
│ 10  │ 9     │ 1.2864  │ -0.37704   │
```